# Type checking in If-then-else expressions

Tags: haskell

I am writing the Monad instance for a parser, and in trying to implement bind I am encountering some type checking errors. The following code does not type check:

```
(=<<) :: (a -> Parser b) -> Parser a -> Parser b
f =<< p = P (\s -> let x = parse p s
                   in if isErrorResult x
                      then x
                      else let (Result i a) = x
                           in parse (f a) i)
```

GHCi complains that the last line of code `parse (f a) i` is expecting type `ParseResult b` but received type `ParseResult a`. However, if I remove the error checking code then everything type checks just fine:

```
f =<< p = P (\s -> let x = parse p s
                   in let (Result i a) = x
                      in parse (f a) i)
```

So what is it about the if-then-else expression that causes the type confusion?

Comment: This makes sense, because as far as I understand Your code the x is of type `a`. And so, in the first version bind can return either `ParseResult a` (in `then x`) or 'ParseResult b` (from `parse (f a) i`)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Compare:

```
data Boring a = Boring

doesn'tTypeCheck :: Boring a -> Boring b
doesn'tTypeCheck x = x

doesTypeCheck :: Boring a -> Boring b
doesTypeCheck Boring = Boring
```

Your situation is analogous: though your error result `x` probably doesn't actually have any `a` values inside, its type is still tagged with `a`. You'll need to "retag" it with `b`. It's probably cleanest to do this by switching from `if` to a `case` statement, as in

```
case parse p s of
    Error e {- :: ParseResult a -} -> Error e {- :: ParseResult b -}
    Result i a -> parse (f a) i
```